# SNMP walk on Virtual Ip not working? what can be the reason

Tags: windows, sql-server, cluster

I have two MSSQLcluster, at a time VIP [virtual ip] that will be assigned to on of the master. The problem is when i try to do any snmpwalk on VIP from a different machine its returning me a time out. I don't see anything come back from the cluster resource, it's almost like the resource IP ignores it.

But when i try on the Hosts ip where vip is assigned its working what can be the reason?

I had checked community string port etc its configured correctly

Thanks
Sandeep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I am aware snmp is not a cluster aware application so if you do an snmp request on the VIP it will respond over the node's physical IP.

There is a good explanation on the [microsoft forums](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/026556f3-3cfb-4723-a229-35e9d86945bb/clustering-snmp-monitoring-and-firewalls)